# Android mp3 file in raw folder?

Tags: android, mp3, android-resources

Ihave a small mp3 file.It's size is less than 4MB.When I add that mp3 file to res/raw folder of project,I get `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR` error in installation.But when I remove mp3 file all things work fine.How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure your filename is not contain numbers and any symbols..

Comment: I had changed install location in ,anifest and file name has no error(it containes a-z,0-9,_) only.

Comment: Do you have `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` in your manifest and a device/avd with very little free capacity in external storage?

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your manifest like here http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/solved-install_failed_container_error.19415/